# Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to BitmapImage

Tags: c#, wpf

I am building a WPF application in which I am getting an error as

> Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to type 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage'

**XAML Code**:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Active" Width="60">
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
       <Button>
            <Button.Content>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myImageConverter}"
                              ConverterParameter="Active">
                    <Binding Path="IsClosed"/>
                    <Binding Path="IsChecked"/>
                    <Binding Path="IsActive"/>
                    <Binding Path="TickImage"/>
                    <Binding Path="CrossImage"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

**C# Converter Code**:

```
public class ImageConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool isClosed = (bool)values[0];
        bool isChecked = (bool)values[1];
        bool isActive = (bool)values[2];
        Image img = new Image();

        switch ((string)parameter)
        {
            case "Active":
                if (isClosed == true && isChecked == true)
                {
                    if (isActive == true)
                    {
                        img.Source = (BitmapImage)values[3];
                        img.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        img.Source = (BitmapImage)values[4];
                        img.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
                    }
                }
                break;
        }

        return img;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

TickImage and CrossImage are properties of the ViewModel Class. They are initialized in the ViewModel constructor as shown below.

```
TickImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("K:\\projects\\ContentSets\\Ownership\\SOMA\\Staging\\SOMA\\Images\\icon_tick.gif", UriKind.Absolute));
CrossImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("K:\\projects\\ContentSets\\Ownership\\SOMA\\Staging\\SOMA\\Images\\icon_cross.gif", UriKind.Absolute));
TickImage.Freeze();
CrossImage.Freeze();
```

IsClosed, IsChecked and IsActive are properties of DataObject Class.

The error occurs at the 1st line of the condition `if (isActive == true)`

I have also tried the following XAML code:

```
<Button.Content>
    <Image>
        <Image.Source>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myImageConverter}"
                  ConverterParameter="Active">
                <Binding Path="IsClosed"/>
                <Binding Path="IsChecked"/>
                <Binding Path="IsActive"/>
                <Binding Path="TickImage"/>
                <Binding Path="CrossImage"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Image.Source> 
    </Image>
</Button.Content>
```

TickImage and CrossImage are simple strings in the ViewModel and with necessary changes in the Converter the same error is thrown as follows

> Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to type 'System.String'

Comment: Please note that there is no need to write `if (isActive == true)`. It is simply written as `if (isActive)`

Comment: And what about `img = (string)values[3];` two lines later? Does that make any sense?

Comment: Why not just set a breakpoint at the line in question and check what's in `values[3]`?

Comment: `img = (string)values[3];` is not a part of the code...I am sorry for that... `values[3]` and `values[4]` contain `{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your bindings are incorrect. When you perform a binding inside a `CellTemplate` you're actually binding to the cell's DataContext rather than your view's DataContext (i.e the viewmodel).

You should try modifying your bindings to take the values from your viewmodel, like this for example:

```
<Binding Path="DataContext.TickImage" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}" />
```

Comment: I am a little new to WPF so this may sound as a dumb question but why is `AncestorType=DataGrid` when TickImage is defined in the ViewModel...I mean shouldn't the AncestorType be `UserControl` ...(Though the code works for both values of `AncestorType`...I do not know how).

Comment: `DataContext` is an inherited dependency property, so the DataGrid gets the same DataContext as the UserControl (unless it was changed explicitly somewhere in the visual tree between the UserControl and the DataGrid). You can use either, but in this case using `DataGrid` avoids an unnecessary walk further up the visual tree.