# Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to DoctorModel

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have an entity type called Doctor that I have created a model so that I can then use `INotifyPropertyChange` on the items in the entity. In my model called `DoctorModel`, I have the following function which will give me the exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to DoctorModel

```
    // OVERLOADED METHODS
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return ID ^ 7;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        // Check for null  
        if (ReferenceEquals(obj, null))
            return false;
        // Check for same reference  
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
            return true;
        var model = (DoctorModel)obj;   <-- Exception HERE -->
        return this.ID == model.ID;
    }
```

EDIT:
I am creating a ObservableCollection of this type but when I try to remove an element, it will not remove from it. I saw an article on a site that showed to use this technique when tying to do what I described. The article I am referring to is at the following: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/tirthacs/remove-an-item-form-observable-collection-using-remove/

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18866308/861716

Answer (score 2):

Just posting my solution to my question in case someone else could benefit from it.

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
  return string.Format("DoctorModel{0}", this.ID.ToString()).GetHashCode();
}

public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
   var newObj = obj as DoctorModel;

   if (null != newObj)
   {
       return this.GetHashCode() == newObj.GetHashCode();
   }
   else
   {
       return base.Equals(obj);
   }
}
```