# Unable to cast object in WPF MultiValueConverter

Tags: c#, wpf, imultivalueconverter

I am trying to learn `MultiBinding`. 
I try to pass two values (one `double` and one `boolean`) from viewmodel to the converter and return a `string` result back.

**XAML**

```
<TextBlock>
     <TextBlock.Text>
         <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyValueConverter}">
              <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ScrollViewer}" Path="DataContext.SelectedCar.PowerValue" />
              <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ScrollViewer}" Path="DataContext.SelectedCar.IsPowerAvailable" />
         </MultiBinding>
     </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

**Converter**

```
class MyValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (System.Convert.ToBoolean(values[1]))
        {
            return string.Format("{0:n1}", values[0]); 
        }
        else
        {
            return "[not available]";
        }
    }
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Viewmodel**

```
public double PowerValue
public bool IsPowerAvailable
```

In the converter I will get an exception `Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to type 'System.IConvertible`.

What does this mean? Did I implement the `MultiBinding` incorrectly?

**EDIT:**

ViewModel looks like this

```
class CarViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private car _selectedCar;
    public car SelectedCar
    {
        get { return _selectedCar; }
        set
        {
            _selectedCar = value;
        }
    }
```

Model looks like this:

```
class car 
{
    public double PowerValue { get; set; }
    public bool IsPowerAvailable{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You might find some hints in this similar topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866308/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-ms-internal-namedobject-to-bitmapimage

Comment: Why do you use relativeSource ? Do you have different datacontexts ?

Comment: No, I just have one datacontext. I tried quite a few alternatives, also without RelativeSource but they didn't work either

Comment: Where is this textblock used? just within a window/usercontrol or inside a datatemplate?

Comment: TextBlock is insdie ScrollViewer and there inside a Grid. No DataTemplates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is due to the fact that the `DataContext.SelectedCar.IsPowerAvailable` can't be reached, make sure that the `SelectedCar` property is indeed reachable from the `ScrollViewer` DataContext, here a working sample

```
 Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" 
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
<Window.Resources>
    <wpfApplication12:MyValueConverter x:Key="MyValueConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>      
  <ScrollViewer>
        <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyValueConverter}">
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ScrollViewer}" Path="DataContext.SelectedCar.PowerValue" />
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ScrollViewer}" Path="DataContext.SelectedCar.IsPowerAvailable" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

and the selectedCar is defined in the VM/CodeBhind:

```
private Car _selectedCar = new Car()
    {
        IsPowerAvailable = true,
        PowerValue = 14
    };
    public Car SelectedCar
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedCar;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_selectedCar == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _selectedCar = value;                
        }
    }
```

Comment: If DataContext.SelectedCar.IsPowerAvailable can't be reached why can I correctly get the value by changing the binding to Text="{Binding SelectedCar.PowerValue, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat=n1}" (edited also the initial post to show viewmodel and model)

Comment: by Text="{Binding SelectedCar..you are using the TextBlock DataContext, in the sample you provided  you are using the the ScrollViewer DataContextx (..AncestorType=ScrollViewer ), make sure your ScrollViewer's DataContext is properly set!, if so pls show me you full xaml

Comment: In my UserControl I have set <ScrollViewer.DataContext>
            <viewmodel:CarViewModel/>
        </ScrollViewer.DataContext> and datacontext is not set anywhere else. TextBlock is inside the ScrollViewver

Comment: Do it just with a binding without the relativeResouce and it should work. <Binding Path="SelectedCar.PowerValue"/>

Comment: Well, the above code works fine to me, i 've reproduce a sample based on your description, make sure there no typo or whatsoever!

Comment: @NawedNabiZada indeed the relative source is extra work, i've just intentionally leave it since i don't have a full view of the hole xaml page

Comment: @user2143213 By the way, you are not Calling the OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCar"), so even if your property is changed, then you UI doesn't know, and cannot update. Make sure that OnPropertyChanged is called when you are setting your SelectedCar

Comment: OnPropertyChanged is implemented -> I just left it out here intentionally

Comment: Changed binding to <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource KeyFigureValueConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="SelectedCar.PowerValue" />
                            <Binding Path="SelectedCar.IsPowerAvailable" />
                        </MultiBinding> but the error remains  the same. Debugging the converter shows values[] contains two items with DependencyProperty.UnsetValue. Is it ok? Can it be converted to Boolean ?

Comment: that proves my point that some how the ScrollViewer DataContext isn't properly set, as a last resort here the project sample that ive created, run it at your end https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=837568D051BAD7CE!2832&authkey=!ANYFs1P7qgiCeaw&ithint=file%2czip

Comment: Yes, indeed it was a DataContext problem. Converter was called in a real application earlier than viewmodel/properties were set up. Adding a check to the beginiing of converter to check the parameter for Boolean type solved this problem.