# String Converter is Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, exception

I have created a converter that compares a single string with a comma delimited string and returns yes if a single match is found. I am getting an exception

"System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to type 'System.String'."

```
    public class IsEqual : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string value1 = (string)values[1];
        string[] splitVal = value1.Split(",".ToArray(), System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            foreach (var item in splitVal)
            {
                try
                {
                    string comparison = (string)values[0];

                    char[] delimiters = new char[1];
                    delimiters[0] = ',';

                    string[] split = ((string)values[1]).Split(delimiters);

                    foreach (string str in split)
                    {
                        if (comparison == str)
                        {
                            return String.Format("yes");
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return String.Format("Error: " + ex.ToString());
                }
                return String.Format("no");
            }
            return null;
        }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Within the mark up it is used as a DataTemplate in a DataGridColumn to indicate that a match is found:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Match">
<StackPanel>
    <Ellipse x:Name="Matches_Icon" Background="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed" Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBox x:Name="value0" Text="{Binding ElementName=SingleItem,Path=Text,Mode=OneWay,TargetNullValue=0}" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="value1" Text="{Binding CommaDeliminatedItem,Mode=OneWay,TargetNullValue=0}" />
        <TextBox x:Name="Result" >
            <TextBox.Text>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource IsEqual}">
                    <Binding ElementName="value0" Path="Text" Mode="OneWay" TargetNullValue="0" />
                    <Binding ElementName="value1" Path="Text" Mode="OneWay" TargetNullValue="0" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
<DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Result,Path=Text}" Value="yes">
        <Setter TargetName="SelectedArt_Icon" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Result,Path=Text}" Value="no">
        <Setter TargetName="SelectedArt_Icon" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
    </DataTrigger>
</DataTemplate.Triggers>
```

To delve further, 'value1' in the XAML binding is the data that is in the DataGrid, value0 is supplied from outside the data grid. When a match is found, 'yes' is returned (don't know why we didn't use boolean..) and that triggers visibility property for the ellipse.

There should not be a null value being passed in so I do not know where this error is coming in.

EDIT from the log:
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to type 'System.String'.
   at CustomMashupUI.IsEqual.Convert(Object[] values, Type targetTypes, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Windows.Data.MultiBindingExpression.TransferValue()
   at System.Windows.Data.MultiBindingExpression.Transfer()
   at System.Windows.Data.MultiBindingExpression.UpdateTarget(Boolean includeInnerBindings)
   at System.Windows.Data.MultiBindingExpression.AttachToContext(Boolean lastChance)
   at System.Windows.Data.MultiBindingExpression.MS.Internal.Data.IDataBindEngineClient.AttachToContext(Boolean lastChance)
   at MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.Task.Run(Boolean lastChance)
   at MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.Run(Object arg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)

Comment: You should specify what line your error is on. I'm wondering if it is as simple as the fact that `values[1]` is not in fact a string so your cast on the first line is failing.

Comment: See [Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to BitmapImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866308/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-ms-internal-namedobject-to-bitmapimage). Maybe your binding is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that values is an array of objects. If you want to convert the members into a string type use:

```
string value1 = values[1].ToString();
```

or

```
string value1 = Convert.ToString(values[1]);
```