# How does ComboBox MultiBinding bind to SelectedItem's property

Tags: wpf, multibinding

I am using **MultiBinding** for a **ComboBox**. One of the parameters I want to bind is the `SelectedItem's SelectedName`. Here `SelectedName` is `string` type.

If NOT  **MultiBinding**, I have this that works well:

```
<ComboBox Background="{Binding SelectedItem.SelectedName, 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}">
```

But in **MultiBinding** when I tried to bind to `SelectedItem.SelectedName` it reports

> Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to type
> 'System.String'.

This is my code:

```
<ComboBox.Background>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyMultiBindingConverter}">
        <Binding .../>
        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="SelectedItem.SelectedName"/> //this line fails
    </MultiBinding>
</ComboBox.Background>
```

How can I make it correct? Thanks.

**Updated information:**

The `ComboBox` does not have a default `SelectedItem`. When I use `MyConverter`, If I have not selected an item, the breakpoint in `Convert` method will not be hit. After I selected an item the breakpoint is hit which is the behavior I want.

However when I use `MyMultiBindingConverter` the situation is completely inverse - The breakpoint will be hit on UI load and will not be hit after I selected an item.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to BitmapImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866308/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-ms-internal-namedobject-to-bitmapimage)

Comment: I believe the context within the `MultiBinding` markup is not what you expect. `{Relative Source Self}` is not going to resolve to the `ComboBox` object. You should probably use `RelativeAncestor` instead. See proposed duplicate.

Comment: Hello @Peter Duniho. I modified it to `<Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBox}" Path="SelectedItem.SelectedName"/>`, still the same error, should I put `DataContext` somewhere?

Comment: Seems `{Relative Source Self}` is no problem - The only difference from 'SingleBinding' is that the breakpoint in `Convert` method will be hit on UI loaded (Although I don't know what causes this difference). After I modify the Converter, it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check whether you get a `string` in your `Convert` method:

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (values.Length < 2)
        return Binding.DoNothing;

    string selectedName = values[1] as string;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedName))
        return Binding.DoNothing;:

    //...
}
```

You can't assume that the `SelectedItem.SelectedName` property returns a value each time the `Convert` method is called.